# How should Pubsub, acting a log sink, fire a function without sending the log?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have been using [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/mlops-with-vertex-ai/blob/main/08-model-monitoring.ipynb) example of creating a Vertex AI monitoring job. It sends an email and have adapted it to send a Pubsub message, with @Jose Gutierrez Paliza's help.

I have got this working, sort of. But what seems to be happening is that Pubsub pushes the log to  a function which errors.

My log sink includes:
[image]

When I look at logs I see an INFO entry:

```
   my-fn an_id Event data: {"insertId":"another_id...
```

followed by a separate ERROR entry:

```
...
ValueError: The pipeline parameter insertId is not found in the pipeline job input definitions.
```

So I assume Pubsub is sending the log to the function which gets extraneous crap, including `insertId`.

I can run the pipeline fine via Jupyter:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub

publish_client = pubsub.PublisherClient()
topic = f'projects/{PROJECT}/topics/{PUBSUB_TOPIC}'
data = {}
message = json.dumps(data)

_ = publish_client.publish(topic, message.encode())
```

So how do I the equivalent via Pubsub?

Comment: It seems like the job parameter `insertId` value is missing. This is possibly related to the Vertex AI source code, could you please check your source-code of Vertex AI? This can happen because the parameter is not found in the job input definitions.

Answer (score 1):

It was the log being used (as `data`) in the following:

```
parameter_values = json.dumps(data).encode()
```

I set:

```
parameter_values={"project": project, "display_name": "some_name"}
```